# How to order strings which represent int values

Tags: c#, arrays

I receive an array which I'm not in control of. Sadly, it comes through as a string although all values are *always* `int` values.

There is no option to change the array so I have to work with it.

I'd like to sort them but of course, "10" (as a string) comes before "4" (as a string). I understand why.

Without converting the values of the array to `int` values, is there a way to order the `strings` as if they were `int`? I know converting is a better way, but curious as to the option when using `string`.

In this example, there will not be negative values

My array could be

```
"10"
"11"
"2"
"4"
```

but I'd like to show it as

```
"2"
"4"
"10"
"11"
```

Comment: Why can't you convert them to `int`s? `strings.OrderBy(int.Parse)` would be the obvious way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can order them by the length of the string first:

```
string[] input = /* wherever it comes from */
string[] result = input.OrderBy(s => s.Length).ThenBy(s => s).ToArray();
```

---

Note that this is only a theoretical solution for your special interest in "not parsing" and only works if the strings contain no negative values or leading zeros and only the characters '0' - '9' (no special unicode number symbols etc). In productive code you definitely should parse the strings to get proper results, as Servy already correctly pointed out in the comments.

Comment: According to you "5" is less than "02"

Comment: @Servy according to OP the string will be "2" not "02".

Comment: The question says no such thing.  It says that they're all integers, that's all.

Comment: This is correct. I can't mark it yet, but I feel this is better than parsing first. Also question states `Without converting the values of the array to `int` values`

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions Are the strings guaranteed to be non negative too?

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions The answer isn't correct, and it produces improper results.  You should *absolutely* be parsing the values.  That's how you actually get the correct value.  That you don't want to do it doesn't change the fact that that is the correct thing for you to do.

Comment: @Servy, yes, and sorry for not being clear as I didn't state reason. My question was more about understanding if there was a way to do it without `int`. I pointed in the question that I knew of this but I didn't make it clear why. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you mean you have to *keep* them as strings, not that you're literally forbidden to ever parse them at all:

```
string[] a = GetArray();

a = a.OrderBy(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```

Comment: I appreciate this is probably the better answer as it's the better way, but as my question was about understanding my option with strings, I've given a plus 1

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions Ah, OK. I did say I was just guessing! Cheers.

Comment: It's probably what I'll end up doing, but my question wasn't about it. I'd give another +1 if I could

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions Oh yeah, not all questions have to be "what's the most respectable boring way to do this in production code". I've written all kinds of weird code just for the sake of it. I wrote a binary adder in Perl once. Talk about useless.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
int maxStringLength = int.MaxValue.ToString().Length;
string[] a = { "1", "11", "20", "2", "10" };
a = a.OrderBy(x => x.PadLeft(maxStringLength, '0')).ToArray();
```

If you know how big your numbers are going to be, you can use a more reasonable value for `maxStringLength`.